# How to get the data-href value of a tag after modal is clicked in Laravel

Tags: php, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i have a modal which opens when the Edit button is clicked now i want that the value of data-href in  with which the modal opens on clicking to echo inside of modal body how can i do that

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="{{ url('admin/product_edit/'.$cat->id) }}" class="edit_product btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"> Edit</a>
```

Comment: add onClick fucntion and pass this.data-href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.relatedTarget` function have more `dynamic` approach to get the `data-attributes`.

You do **not** need to use an inline `onclick` function here this can be done easily using the native `jQuery` bootstrap function like `show.bs.modal` and get the `a` data attributes on click and to be displayed in the modal.

```
$("#editModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) //Button that triggered the modal
  var getHref = button.data('href') //get button href
  $('#href').text(getHref) //show in the modal
})
```

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$("#editModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) //Button that triggered the modal
  var getHref = button.data('href') //get button href
  console.log(getHref) //{{ url('admin/product_edit/'.$cat->id) }}
  $('#href').text(getHref) //show in the modal
})
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="{{ url('admin/product_edit/'.$cat->id) }}" class="edit_product btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"> Edit</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <span id="href"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="/sample/url" class="edit_product btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" onclick='process(this)'> Edit</a>

function process(inp) {
    console.log(inp.getAttribute('data-href'));
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use inline functions when using bootstrap and jQuery- See my asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery, then you can do this

```
let hrefVal = null

$('.edit_product').click(function () { hrefVal = $(this).data('href') })
```